# Configure Azure APIM Application with OAuth 2.0 which will secure API with JWT token

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, bearer-token, apim

I have Azure APIM App in which I have configured 'OAuth 2.0 + OpenID Connect' > 'OAuth 2.0' > Add > I have added all required details.

Authorize and token endpoint added here are taken from my Azure AD B2C tenant > App registrations > I have added one App registration (I have added sign in and sign up default recommended user flow) > Endpoints (link with sign up and sign in policy).

Everything seems perfect, but when I test API, when I choose authorization flow > authorization_code > it will open a pop up > As I am already signed in to APIM app here, it is automatically signing in and again showing APIM app home screen within pop up window.

Ideally it should add bearer token in headers as an authorization header. but it is not working as expected.

let me know if I am missing anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have configured OAuth 2.0 in my APIM instance in the following way-

[image]
[image]
[image]

- You need to add **Authorization code grant flow** URL in the registered app as shown below.

[image]

- After making these changes, I published the developer portal. Here I haven't enabled Azure AD.

[image]

- A sign in page got popped up as soon as I selected **authorization_code** in Authorization.

[image]

- After signing in successfully, I can see the token got amended in the header.

[image]

- I am able to get 200 OK response.

[image]